# Смена IP-адреса в A-записи при недоступности сервера

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-сервер, dns

**Положим**, что у меня есть два разных хостинга с идентичными сайтами. В настройках ресурсных записях DNS я могу указать несколько А-записей с разными IP-адресами, и в таком случае система начинает по одному доменному имени отдавать разные IP. Это происходит либо хаотично, либо циклично.

**Что нужно**: я хочу, чтобы для одного доменного имени использовался только один IP (например, первый в списке). Если же сервер по этому IP недоступен, то чтобы клиент использовал второй IP из списка. Грубо говоря, я хочу, чтобы была некоторая приоритетность.

Вопросы:

1. Можно ли такую схему работы реализовать через ресурсные записи DNS?
2. Если нельзя, то какими иными способами можно добиться подобной схемы работы?

Comment: Ну уровне самой DNS нельзя. В таких случаях обычно ставят на единственную запись очень маленький TTL и в случае необходимости переключения меняют IP в записи (возможно через dynamic DNS).

Comment: Как вариант используют один IP на несколько серверов. и на этом ip либо балансер нагрузки, либо сам ip переходит с сервера на сервер при аварии и все решается на уровне маршрутизации (но это уже не на простых хостингах,  а обычно на своих мощностях, со своей автономной системой)

Comment: На Хабре рассказывали, что некоторым DNS-серверам плевать на TTL и всё равно всё кэшируется на неделю. Поэтому нельзя.

Comment: @andreymal Интересно было бы посмотреть, кто что писал про такие кривые DNS. А то ведь даже яндекс делает на это ставку ...

Comment: @Mike да и для DynDNS это очень важно, однако вот. (А где я это читал, я теперь найти что-то не могу)

Comment: Если бы у меня появилась такая задача, я бы сделал так: 1) поднял бы домен; 2) разрешил бы в BIND'е изменение зоны через его встроенное API по ключу; 3) поднял бы какую-нибудь систему мониторинга; 4) приделал бы к триггеру отпадания основного сервера скрипт, обновляющий А-запись в зоне через API.